# axios.get() is combining the url when sending requests to the backend.

Tags: react-redux, axios

I'm sending a request to the backend via axios calls the URL on my address bar is 
"localhost:3000/topics/5ba06e74dbc"

but in my browser inspector its returning an error

"localhost:3000/topics/api/topics/5ba06e74dbc 404 (Not Found)" 
the request should be:
"localhost:3000/api/topics/5ba06e74dbc" 
anyone know why that extra "topics/" is being added in front of the api call?

```
// my action call I suspect it might be because of my routes or because 
//Im calling from topics/ already.
export const viewTopic = (id) => dispatch => {
  return axios.get(`api/topics/${id}`).then(res => {
    return dispatch({
          type: VIEW_TOPIC,
          payload: res.data
      });
   });
}
```

take a peek at my GitHub or ask for more info, I'm not sure what to include.

https://github.com/wolffles/bloccit-node/tree/frontend

Comment: Have you tried with /api/topics/${id} ? (start your url with / )

Comment: lol thanks I didn't know that means its a relative path

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add a leading slash to the url. Otherwise, it's a relative path and that happens.

`api/topics/${id}` -> `/api/topics/${id}`