# Why axios appends the current URL to API calls in Laravel / React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, laravel, ecmascript-6, redux

I'm trying to make a simple project work in Laravel, React and Redux. This is a function called from a Redux Saga worker:

```
function getTasks() {
    return axios.get('/api/tasks').then(response => response.data);
}
```

Now if the React root component is in the home (URL http://localhost:8000), the request is made to the URL http://localhost:8000/api/tasks and everything works fine. But if the root component is in another page, e.g. http://localhost:8000/home, the request is made to http://localhost:8000/api/tasks/home and obviously it doesn't work. I don't understand why the current URL is appended to the requested URL, the contrary would have made more sense.

Any ideas? Thank you in advance.

Comment: If my answer work for you make sure to mark it as accepted. Thanks you

Comment: If this problem really exists as you described it, then I think that's pretty crappy of axios. :/

Comment: @JAAulde I think there are something wrong with his laravel url config

Answer (score 4):

To make sure you have correct api request I recommend you set up the base url for axios like this

```
axios.defaults.baseURL = "http://localhost:8000";

function getTasks() {
    return axios.get('api/tasks').then(response => response.data);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can try to put forward slash for every axios call.
Instead of this

```
axios.get('api/tasks')
```

Use this:

```
axios.get('/api/tasks')
```

Answer (score 1):

It had nothing to do with any of this, my question couldn't be answered because there wasn't enough context. Basically the problem was in the React Router, the following route was called and *id* was assigned to *home*, so the executed code was in the *Task* component and the API call was different.

```
<Route path='/:id' component={Task} />
```

Comment: if you didn't find a solution for this. here it is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52525634/axios-get-is-combining-the-url-when-sending-requests-to-the-backend

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to always get the root url:

```
let url = window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.host;
```

and then do

```
function getTasks() {
    return axios.get(url + '/api/tasks').then(response => response.data);
}
```

or better yet add it as

```
window.axios.defaults.baseURL = url;
```