# Issue with Vue.js devServer.proxy

Tags: express, vue.js

So in an application that I'm working on currently I'm trying to proxy requests from a Vue-frontend, to an Express-server. The express server is running on localhost:5000. This is in my vue.config.js:

```
    "devServer": {
    "proxy": {
      "^/api/": {
        "target": "http://localhost:5000",
        "ws": true,
        "changeOrigin": true
      }
    }
  },
```

What I can't wrap my head around is why in most cases, sending out requests to my server with just *api/routename* works just fine. Then in only 2 components it doesn't work. In the components where it does work, a GET request looks like this for example:

```
axios.get('api/base/verified')
.then...
```

Then in two other components, according to the same principle of just requesting to *api/route-name*, I'm getting errors. In development mode, the requests then all of a sudden go out to http://localhost:8080/api..., and when trying to deploy, they go to 5000, but I get this error message:

xhr.js:184 GET http://localhost:5000/api/content/course/5f54f3c60bb7a30017c1abf2 net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Does anyone have any idea about what the deal is, and why the proxying is acting so differently, depending on environment and component?

Comment: Which port are you using in deployment `8080` or `5000`?

Answer (score 0):

You should always use the url with a leading slash e.g. `/api/base/verified` See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52525634/2438933). So I guess in your case that 2 components may use in different path.

The reason it's different for different environments is that the `proxy` is working only in development server that's why they called `devServer`.

I'm not sure why you got that error it seems there must be another config that can go to port `5000` such as proxy in nginx but `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` usually means there is no server at that endpoint.

Comment: This worked just fine! Thanks. Still don't understand how it worked in some components, but the leading slash did the job.